# Failed to install tts-watson

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, text-to-speech, watson

I'm trying to install tts-watson 1.0.0 to my Mac OS X Sierra using the following:

```
    sudo pip install tts-watson
```

The installing started and then
I get this error:

```
    error: could not create'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share': Operation not permitted

----------------------------------------
    Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-NMf7OP/anyconfig/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Asdffe-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-NMf7OP/anyconfig/
```

Please help me to get this fixed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I read, that the project github and pypi pages suggest pip install, but maybe a user space install via `pip install --user tts-watson` might be a good fit, as permission to create something down in the /System/Library path was denied?

Comment: @Dilettant I get `Successfully installed tts-watson-1.0.0`. Seems like everything is okay, but it's not as I'm trying this: `from tts_watson.TtsWatson import TtsWatson` and get this error `ImportError: No module named tts_watson.TtsWatson`. Any ideas?

Comment: I would inspect the folders noted in the Succesfully installed messages, I suspect the pip targeted a different python interpreters places... python -v should be very verbose, but when you then try to import, it lists nicely where it tries to find ... maybe add the user folder it installed to to sys.path in your python session to try ...

Comment: @Dilettant Thank you so much, you really helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is port audio. To fix this problem, install portaudio.

On Mac,

```
brew install portaudio
```

On Linux,

```
apt-get install portaudio19-dev
```